# perl -s switch documentation confusion

Tags: perl, perldoc

Examples on stackoverflow involving `-s switch` (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29613573/14557599) give position of `--` like:

```
perl -s -e 'if ($xyz) { print "$xyz\n" }' -- -xyz
```

`perldoc perlrun`:

> ```
> -s   enables rudimentary switch parsing for switches on the command line
>      after the program name but before any filename arguments (or before
>      an argument of --). Any switch found there is removed from @ARGV
>      and sets the corresponding variable in the Perl program. The
>      following program prints "1" if the program is invoked with a -xyz
>      switch, and "abc" if it is invoked with -xyz=abc.
>
>          #!/usr/bin/perl -s
>          if ($xyz) { print "$xyz\n" }
> ```

I'm confused with "before an argument of --", because example above works, -xyz is **after** `--`. If written as in docs:

```
perl -xyz -- -s -e 'if ($xyz) { print "$xyz\n" }' 
Can't open perl script "-s": No such file or directory
```

Per my understanding how it works I want to write in doc:

> after the program name (or after an argument of --) but before any
> filename arguments

Is my change correct? Maybe sometime before syntax of perlrun was indeed as described in docs but was changed later but docs were updated to reflect that?

***Edit 2:***

After reading all the answers:

> after the program name (or after first occurrence of an argument of -- if the program is specified via -e or -E switches) but before any filename arguments (or before --, first occurrence in case of program name and second in case of the program specified via -e or -E switches)

***TL;DR***

Edit:

In response to am answer by zdin (note: I have not found definition of `option`, `switch`; seems those are synonyms and both are used as both bash command line arguments and in perl program on shebang line arguments).

```
echo a-a-a > 1.txt
```

q.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -sp
s/a/b/;
if ($xyz) { print "$xyz\n" }
```

w.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -s
s/a/b/;
if ($xyz) { print "$xyz\n" }
```

I can call *.pl passing 1.txt as argument w/out `--`:

```
./q.pl -xyz=a 1.txt 
a
b-a-a

perl -p ./q.pl -xyz=a 1.txt 
a
b-a-a
```

One-liner:

```
perl -spe 's/a/b/;if ($xyz) { print "$xyz\n" }' -- -xyz=a 1.txt
a
b-a-a
```

That shows my reformulation is valid for both running via program name and one-liners.

P.S.

```
perl --version

This is perl 5, version 34, subversion 0 (v5.34.0) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
```

Comment: As for the statement in the edit, "_That shows my reformulation is valid for both running via program name and one-liners._"  -- well, no, it doesn't. That reformulation: "_after the program name (or after an argument of `--`) but before any filename arguments_" isn't right -- everything after `--` are put into `@ARGV`, period (for a program in a file (not one-liner); if we want things to be assigned per `-s` that must comes before `--`, if there is `--` (which is sometimes unnecessary).  Try it -- that's one thing you don't show.   That's the point of `--`.  One-liner's different though...

Comment: @zdin, I've reformulated (see Edit 2). It it long adding `first` and `second`, but writing basically `after -- but before --` seems confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quoted statement in perldoc is correct, if incomplete as it doesn't mention a different behavior for a one-liner. The confusion stems from peculiarities of option parsing with `-s` in presence.

That particular statement refers to running a program-in-a-file, as shown.  With

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -s

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

our $tt;  # -s populates package variables

say $tt // "no -tt...";
```

we can do

```
perl test_s_switch.pl -tt=X -- arguments
```

to mark the end of options ("switches"), after which arguments come (for `@ARGV`). This is needed if the first of the following arguments happens to look like an option (starts with `-`); or we can leave out `--` otherwise (if the first argument doesn't start with `-`), or if no arguments are being passed

```
perl test_s_switch.pl -tt=X
```

These print `X`.  (Or `perl -s test_s_switch.pl ...` w/o the `-s` on the shebang line.)

But for a command-line program ("one-liner") it goes the way you observe

```
perl -s -wE'say $tt // "no -tt"' -- -tt=X
```

and we get `X` printed.  Here the `--` is necessary to indicate end of options so that after it go arguments.  This distinction is stated at the beginning of [Command Switches in perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#Command-Switches)

> A `--` signals the end of options and disables further option processing. Any arguments after the `--` are treated as filenames and arguments.

The reason for this difference is that with the program given in a file the options ("switches") must come before the program-filename, what leaves the place for `-tt=X` (argument for `-s`) to come right after the program-filename, before `--` or arguments. But with a command-line program ("one-liner") the program itself is a part of a switch (`-e'...'`) so other options may follow, so to pass an argument for `-s` (`-tt=X`) we must have `--` first, to indicate the end of options.  Tricky, eh.

With a one-liner, trying without `--` makes `-tt=X` into switches (`t`, `t`, and `=X`)

```
perl -s -wE'say $tt // "no -tt"' -tt=X   # um, no...
```

and results in

```
Unrecognized switch: -=X  (-h will show valid options).
```

since `-t` is a legitimate switch and repeating it (`-tt`) is accepted.

---

At this point I have to note a remark at the end of the [-s switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-e-commandline) description in `perlrun`

> ...
> For these reasons, use of `-s` is discouraged. See [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt::Long) for much more flexible switch parsing.

Comment: Please see my Edit to the question. I've found out `--` seems unnecessary (al least with `-s`), so my suggestion of reformulation stands (for now).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, only after reading it I've realized switches can be written on shebang line and it affects understanding of the man page.

Comment: @Martian2020, Re "*I've found out `--` seems unnecessary*", It is *sometimes* unnecessary, yes. It is only needed if the options are followed by something that looks like an option but isn't. e.g. `-x` and `-x --` are equivalent, and `-x y` and `-x -- y` are equivalent, but `-x -y` and `-x -- -y` are *not* equivalent.

Comment: @Martian2020 "_I've found out `--` seems unnecessary_" -- well, it may be; see the first two examples in this post -- the argument/value for `-s` comes _before_ `--`, if there is a need for `--` (to indicate end of options==switches).  The problem is with `-s` -- with the argument/value for it coming after the program-filename we _must_ indicate the end of that so to supply actual arguments (for `@ARGV`).  But, if there is no need for that, then there is no need for `--`.

Comment: @Martian2020 "_my suggestion of reformulation stands_"  -- well, no, it doesn't.  While I'm completely with you that this is all confusing, your suggestion from the question -- "_(or after an argument of --) but before any filename arguments_" --  is not possible: what comes after `--` _are taken as arguments_.  The argument/value for `-s` must come before `--`_.  Try otherwise.  Take my script and run it by giving the `-s` a value (`--tt=X`) after `--` ... it won't be taken.  Add a print of `@ARGV` to the script and you'' see a string `-tt=X` as an `@ARGV` element.  It must come _before_ `--`

Comment: @Martian2020  ... unless it's a one-liner!  In which case the `--` are indeed needed first, to stop options ("switches") processing, and then the first thing affter `--` need be the argument=value for `-s` (that `-tt=X`).  So your observation is correct for a one-liner, as I state.  This is all really bad, and the problem is the `-s` capability, which requires a little special processing

Comment: Thanks, now when combined yours answer and one from ikegami I see case with program name and w/out are different. So at least as you wrote docs are not complete and IMO worth amending.

Comment: @Martian2020 "_... docs are not complete and IMO worth amending._"   -- I absolutely agree with that.  I'd say that this is worth a bug report, and that docs should be expanded a little to clarify `-s` handling for one-liner as well.

Comment: @Martian2020 Added a specific statement for when `--` is necessary for a file-program, to (hopefully) help clarify that part.   (I still think that the core of the problem is the different _and undocumented_ placement of `--` in a one-liner.)

Comment: Seems to me you know the topic much deeper than myself. Do you want to file a bug report? If not, can you advice where to file one? TIA

Comment: @Martian2020 This is about documentation but that'd go as a Perl bug report, and the place to do it is [the bug tracker](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues).  (There's also [perlbug](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlbug) that is informative to read but that tool cannot file bug reports anymore.)  ...

Comment: @Martian2020 [cont'd]   I think that the crux of your question is a good description and your title would be a good title, perhaps with a little more specifics (or not?).  And offer your best take on what the change would be like.  Before doing that I'd recommend a little more contemplation over what _is_ available in docs (there's stuff at several places, and I quote a couple) and what all that info conveys altogether.

Comment: @Martian2020 If you find all this too messy I can look into it once I find some time to go over the existing docs carefully, so to be able to document the request to improve them

Comment: @Martian2020 (I meant to say let me know if you want me to consider it....)

Comment: "Before doing that I'd recommend a little more contemplation", I'm still thinking about it, if I'm up to the task I mean, considering you advice the report be not only of my findings about `-s`.

Comment: @Martian2020 "_...not only of my findings about `-s`_" -- right, it does matter what is at other places in the docs, specially in the same page (`perlrun`), and what overall one can get from all of it.  I'll look over it then, to see first whether (I think that) it indeed needs an improvement and, rather, how badly.

Answer (score 3):

First, perl processes the arguments to the perl interpreter, ending with the first `--` or non-option argument (The filename unless you're using `-e`). Stuff after that point populates `@ARGV`. Then if present the `-s` argument causes those arguments to be processed for options, stopping at the first non-option or `--`. So you can have two instances of `--`, each signalling to stop processing a *different* set of options, one for perl itself, one for the program being run. Some examples:

```bash
# No --
$ perl -s -E 'say "@ARGV"; say $c' -c a b c
-e syntax OK
# -- to stop perl option processing
$ perl -s -E 'say "@ARGV"; say $c' -- -c a b c
a b c
1
# Two --'s, one for perl options, one for -s options
# Blank line because no $c is being set (Would generate a warning
# with -w/use warnings. Does set $xyz)
$ perl -s -E 'say "@ARGV"; say $c' -- -xyz -- -c a b c
-c a b c

# ex.pl does the same as the code for the above -E option. Its presence stops
# perl option processing
$ perl -s ex.pl -c a b c
a b c
1
# -- to stop -s option processing; sets $xyz
$ perl -s ex.pl -xyz -- -c a b c
-c a b c

# With a filename starting with - so it's treated as a filename not an option
$  perl -s -- -ex.pl -c a b c
a b c
1
# And two instances of --
perl -s -- -ex.pl -- -c a b c
-c a b c
```

Comment: Thanks. At least as mentioned by zdim the man page `-s` description does not apply to one-liners (no program name there) and it is IMO worth amending.

Comment: I've reformulated (see Edit 2). It it long adding `first` and `second`, but writing basically `after -- but before --` seems confusing.

Answer (score 3):

It's referring to the first `--` *script* argument, as opposed to the first `--` *`perl`* argument.

---

Let's assumes `file.pl` starts with

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -s
```

Normally, one uses

```bash
file.pl -j             # $j = 1;
```

Now let's say you wanted `-k` to end up in `@ARGV` instead of being treated as an option. We can't use

```bash
file.pl -k             # $k = 1;  XXX
```

So we add a `--`.

```bash
file.pl -- -k          # @ARGV = '-k';
```

Combined:

```bash
file.pl -j -- -k       # $j = 1; @ARGV = '-k';
```

Now, what if you used `perl -se'...'` instead? Until the first argument that doesn't start with `-`, arguments are passed to `perl`, not `-s` or the script. So you have to mark the end of arguments instead.

```bash
perl -se'...' -i -- -j -- -k
```

- `-i` is processed by `perl`, activating in-place editing.
- `-j` is processed by `-s`, resulting in `$j = 1`.
- `-k` is placed in `@ARGV`.

Comment: "Normally, one uses file.pl -j # $j-=1"., I've looked though `man perlrun` carefully and found only one way to pass variables: `-s` switch. "Yours" way is new to me and IMO worth including into man page/docs. Also `./q.pl -xyz -- -p 1.txt` results in empty line, `-p` seems not passed as `@ARGV` (e.pl: `s/a/b/;
if ($xyz) { print "$xyz\n" })`; 1.txt : `a-a-a`). Also I added Edit section to the question.

Comment: My quote from man page: "Any switch
            found there is removed from @ARGV and sets the corresponding variable in the Perl
            program.".  Your answer tells any `@ARGV` is a variable by default. That is IMO confusing.

Comment: Re "*Your answer tells any @ARGV is a variable by default.*", No it doesn't. `-s` is needed for that, and `-s` was used throughout the answer. The question is about `-s`, so explaining the basic behaviour of `-s` is not needed, and it was already provided by the Question anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Now I know default variable value is 1,  and with `-s` it makes sense to use `--` twice. As for docs, in one liner there is no program name, so man page wording is not complete as another answer wrote.

Comment: Yes. Like I said, it's referring to the first `--` *script* argument, as opposed to the first `--` *`perl`* argument.

Comment: I've reformulated (see Edit 2). It it long adding `first` and `second`, but writing basically `after -- but before --` seems confusing.